# Guardar varios datos en un arreglo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando guardar una serie de productos en un arreglo llamado "Datos", pero cada vez que guardo un dato borra el anterior, soy nuevo en esto de JavaScript y estoy practicando, he buscado en internet pero no encuentro solución quizá estoy buscando mal, obtengo el ID de un Select y el nombre del Index de un select, esto lo almaceno con `push` y muestro el arreglo en una tabla y si se muestran los productos que estoy ingresando, pero en el arreglo no los almacena, saludos.

Mi código:

```
function addTemporalyCategories() {

    var categoriaId = document.getElementById('categoriasN').value;
    var selectCategoria = document.getElementById('categoriasN');
    var categoriaNombre = selectCategoria.options[selectCategoria.selectedIndex].text;

    var datos = [];

    datos.push(categoriaId, categoriaNombre);

    var tablaDatos = document.getElementById('categorias-seleccionadas-tabla');

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        tablaDatos.innerHTML += "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>" + "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>";
    }

    console.log(datos);

}
```

Fotografía de la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fotografía del arreglo en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `var datos = [];` se sobreescribe cada vez que entra en la función, debes sacar esta variable fuera

Comment: Gracias @Yussef , muy agradecido!

Comment: Estamos en 2023, porqué razón sigues usando `var` para la declaración de variables?Además, la etiqueta pone [tag:reacts].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te mencionan en los comentarios, tendrías que llevar afuera la variable `datos = [];`, ya que cada vez que se ingresa a la función `addTemporalyCategories()` estás volviendo a inicializar al arreglo `datos` con elementos vacíos y estarías perdiendo a los elementos agregados anteriores. Tu código debería quedar así:

```js
var datos = [];

function addTemporalyCategories() {

    var categoriaId = document.getElementById('categoriasN').value;
    var selectCategoria = document.getElementById('categoriasN');
    var categoriaNombre = selectCategoria.options[selectCategoria.selectedIndex].text;

    datos.push(categoriaId, categoriaNombre);

    var tablaDatos = document.getElementById('categorias-seleccionadas-tabla');

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        tablaDatos.innerHTML += "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>" + "<td>" + datos[i++] + "</td>";
    }

    console.log(datos);

}
```

De esta forma, el arreglo `datos` estará inicializada al comienzo y al entrar en la función se irán almacenando los datos sucesivamente.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias Cris!

Comment: Estamos en 2023, porqué razón sigues usando `var` para la declaración de variables? Además, la etiqueta pone [tag:reacts].

Comment: @MauricioContreras bueno yo solo copié el ejercicio del OP... aunque tienes razón jeje

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo @MauricioContreras , no sé si ya no se usa pero todos los videos que he visto lo usan, es mejor usar Let que var? , saludos